# moving files to new folder in FTP using Python

Tags: python, function, file, sorting, ftp

I am a bit lost. I'm trying to move a bunch of files to a new folder in FTP using python. I have tried a lot of function but what seems to work best is the ftp.rename function. In fact, it works to move only one file at a time to a new folder but it doesn't work to do it for a lot of files (like in my screenshot) using a for loop.
Do you know another technique to move efficiently files in a new folder?
Please help

**This is the code to move a single file :**

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(host, username, password)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"

FtpImage = ftp.mkd("image")
ftp.rename("img1.png", "/image/img1.png")

ftp.quit()
```

**This is the code to move a bunch of files at the same time :**

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(host, username, password)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"
#creating a list with all my files
dirList = ftp.nlst()
#creating a folder
ftpFolder = ftp.mkd("folder1")
#moving my file using their name and adding the folder1 to their name 
for file in dirList:
    ftp.rename(file, "/folder1/" + file)
    # shutil.move(file, "/folder1/" + file )   
ftp.quit()
```

**Error that I get when I run the second programm:**

```
DeprecationWarning: The Tix Tk extension is unmaintained, and the tkinter.tix wrapper module is deprecated in favor of tkinter.ttk
  from tkinter.tix import IMAGETEXT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\q******\projet_python\FTP-sorting\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    ftp.rename(file, "/folder1/")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 604, in rename  
    return self.voidcmd('RNTO ' + toname)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 286, in voidcmd 
    return self.voidresp()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 259, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 254, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Rename /folder1/: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: Please start by posting your code as a text, not as an image. + Show us the error you are getting. + Show us your working code for moving a single file.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When using `shutil`, you use `shutil.move(file, "/folder1/" + file )`. Why do not you try the same with `ftplib`: `ftp.rename(file, "/folder1/" + file)`?

Comment: I have already tried it but it is not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a way to sort my different files :

I had first to sort my dirList (list with all the files) with new sub list (like allDivers) and then I used the following code

```
for file in allDivers:
    destination_folder = "/divers/"
    destination        = destination_folder + file
    ftp.rename(file, destination )
```